# CSS Media Query Image Rule?

Tags: css, image-processing, media-queries, retina-display

I have been experimenting with the CSS Media Query for image substitution on ultra hi-res displays, and they seem to work well for single images defined in the CSS. But, I'm struggling to create intellegent rules as my command of CSS is limited.

Is it possible to use CSS Media Queries to create rule which will substitute any image with an @2x version if one is available? I know there is a jscript that can do this (retina.js) but, it works retrospectively and won't work on images that are rendered dynamically. I thought it would be better to define them in the CSS some how so that they load the correct image first time. Or, am I completely barking up the wrong tree with CSS?